# Variables of type void

Tags: types, swift, void

So I know that `Void` is used to indicate that a function doesn't take or return a value.
In Swift, `Void` is actually a type alias for the empty tuple `()`.

Interestingly (in Beta 6), you can even declare variables of type `Void`:

```
var x: Void
println(x)
x = test()

func test() {}
```

These statements are all legal. The `println()` prints "()".

So far I couldn't figure out what else this can be used for. Why would you need a variable that can't hold any value? Does anyone know a practical use for this, or is this just one of the quirks of Swift?

Comment: In general in all strong typed languages I knew void is returned by any function or method returning nothing. There's no other use in it.

Comment: I just found it strange that you can declare a variable of type void, if you can't use it for anything.

Comment: And thanks to whomever for the down vote on a (in my opinion) legitimate question...

Comment: Yes, that's somehow strange, but I once wrote a programming language where void was even a class.... I would take back my down vote if I could (it's locked know, yes it was me and I wish I didn't vote). I first meant you were asking for the use of void, please clarify that and I will be able to take back my down vote.

Comment: Tried to fix it. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, that's a lot better, I turned my down vote into an up vote. I think the reason of a void variable is to keep everything constant. The return of every function should have the ability to be saved into a variable.

Comment: Actually if one think of `Void` as the `Unit` category a `Void` function returns a value but this value has only one possible value `()`. This is actually a major benefit IMHO over languages like `Java/C#/C++`. Typically in these languages when one create generic function one of often need to do a special overload for functions that returns `Void`. In a language where `Void` actually has a value you don't need that special handling. (In category theory there's a `Void` category which holds no values, it's basically "useless")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: This is a crosspost of [my reply](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1031419#1031419) on the cross-posted question in the Apple Dev Forums.*

It's because Swift seems to be a little academically favourable (it's one of Swift's plus points for me! :-) ).

A mathematical function is a relation between some inputs (the arguments) and some outputs (the return values). Instead of defining a whole class (e.g. "subroutine" or "procedure") for which this doesn't apply (no output, specifically), Swift simply defines a "procedure" as a relation with some set of inputs (possibly empty) and an empty set of outputs.

There are some benefits to it, though, albeit uncommon (at least until functional programming becomes the more dominant style in the language and the community). A little example:

```
infix operator ~~ { precedence 10 associativity right }
func ~~(l: A -> B, r: A) -> B {
     return l(r)
}

let productsSoldIn2014 = productOfSales ~~ salesInYears ~~ [2014]
let salespersonsInvolvedIn2014Sales = salespersonsOfSales ~~ salesInYears ~~ [2014]

fireSalespersons ~~ salespersonsOfSales ~~ salesInYears ~~ [2014]   // Awful companies only.

func salesInYears(_ y: [Int]) -> [Sale] { … }
func productsOfSales(_ s: [Sale]) -> [Product] { … }
func salespersonsOfSales(_ s: [Sale]) -> [SalesPerson] { … }
func fireSalespersons(_ s: [SalesPerson]) -> () { … }               // The appended arrow and null tuple can be left out.
```

I've defined a "chaining" operator `~~` (think of a bending chain) which, right to left, pushes a value through the chain. With some appropriately named functions, we can declaratively define the values we need. (With lazy collections instead of arrays, we approach Haskell paradigms. Unless I'm mistaken, `~~` is here an identity [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). Or it's just a composition operator.)

The third statement (after the two lets) fires the salespersons that sold anything in the year 2014. Note though that `~~` wants to return "fireSalespersons"'s value (to continue the chain on the left, which here isn't present), which in Swift is valid—it's just the null tuple and we discard it. There's no reason why functions without return value shouldn't work with the operator (without overloading it).

By the way, this is also valid:

```
increaseCEOBonus(35000) ~~ fireSalespersons ~~ salespersonsOfSales ~~ salesInYears ~~ [2014]      // Really awful companies only.
//         () -> ()  ~~  [Salesperson] -> ()  ~~  [Sales] -> [Salesperson] …

func increaseCEOBonus(amount: Int)() { … }
```

In this example, the leftmost chain is value-less—it's still left *after* right, but there aren't any values passed to the left. I wouldn't recommend this use though, it's better to simply enumerate each of them on a separate line.

To return to your question, since "nothing" can be consumed (via arguments), it'd be silly to explicitly prohibit "nothing" to be assigned to a variable—arguments are variables.

P.S.: Before anybody asks: yes, I did want to have an excuse to make a contrived example; it was just to test my ability to write complex types.

Comment: You should link to the cross-posted question (if it came first). I think that's one of the requirements of SO's cc-by-sa license. (Either way, it'd be nice to have the link.)

Comment: @royhowie Done. :-) (You'll need an Apple Developer account, of course.)

Answer (score 9):

I came across a practical example where this is useful in dealing with generics. I have a generic class which creates a wrapper around async tasks. One of the methods of the class allows for posting of a result.

Breaking it down to a simplified example:

```
class Foo<T>  {

    var x : T?

    func finishWith(result:T) {
        x = result
        // do more stuff here as a side effect of posting the result
    }
}
```

The question is if you need a Void result i.e.

```
var foo = Foo<Void>()
```

How do you call the `finishWith:result` method?

You can either create a variable with value of void or use '()' as a literal void value:

```
foo.finishWith(result: ())
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably slightly more useful is the `Void?` type, which can be used to store e.g. a `try?` statement that doesn't return a value but you still want to check the success of:

```
let someString = "foo"
let saved: Void? = try? someString.write(toFile: "somePath", atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
if (saved == nil) {
    print("didn't save")
}
```